ros2 launch.py fails to build moveit configuration package
I have been trying loads of different things to try and get my custom urdf/srdf to launch that I created with the moveit2_setup_assistant on ROS 2 Humble (Ubuntu 22.04). I have been somewhat successful with setting up a simple launch file by generating a launch description that loads in the robots parameters (description, semantic, kinematics etc.) and executes a simple movement. However, when it comes to using the "MoveitConfigsBuilder" class, I can't seem to set it up correclt as I get an exception stating that package 'custom_ur_moveit_config' not found and that it is searching in my ros installation. I have also tried to define an absolute path for the class like:
moveit_configs = MoveItConfigsBuilder("/home/usr/ros2_ws/src/ur_custom_config")

But then I get an exception stating that the package doesn't exist. What I am trying is to define the planning_pipelines as is done in this ompl_constrained_planning tutorial. My current directory structure is like this:
ros2_ws/src/
 custom_ur_moveit_config/  
  config/
   controllers.yaml
   kinematics.yaml etc.
   ur10e_robot.srdf 
   ur10e_robot.urdf.xacro
  launch/
   ompl_constrained_path_launch.py
  src/
   ompl_constrained_path_launch.cpp

Based off of the tutorials I am not sure if the urdf file is supposed to be in here and how I am supposed to use the .setup_assistant file? I also have an issue getting the controller manager to spawn the 'ur_manipulator' but I am not sure if this is related?
This is how I am defining my moveit_config in my launch file right now:
moveit_config = (
        MoveItConfigsBuilder("custom_ur_moveit_config")
        .robot_description(file_path="config/ur10e_robot.urdf.xacro")
        .robot_description_semantic(file_path="config/ur10e_robot.srdf")
        .robot_description_kinematics(file_path="config/kinematics.yaml")
        .joint_limits(file_path="config/joint_limits.yaml")
        .trajectory_execution(file_path="config/controllers.yaml")
        .planning_pipelines(pipelines=["ompl"])
        .to_moveit_configs()
    )
    
    # Set planning pipeline parameters
    moveit_config.planning_pipelines["ompl"]["ur_manipulator"][
        "enforce_constrained_state_space"
    ] = True
    moveit_config.planning_pipelines["ompl"]["ur_manipulator"][
        "projection_evaluator"
    ] = "joints(shoulder_pan_joint,shoulder_lift_joint)"


Please improve your question. "My code does not run" is not an appropriate question, especially with https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Thank you for the heads-up I will make the changes ! I'll get back to you on your answer as soon as I have made some changes


Opaque functions are not for beginners. Essentially you are accessing future variables. Try to avoid them like the devil holy water. Most of the time, they are far from necessary and non-ros2-standard - obscuring clear handling and handing over of parameters via LaunchArguments through all launch-files.

Also, your launch-file is too long and therefore not easily readable/debuggable. Separate your launch-file into parts and make a tree structure:


one.launch.py
├── two.launch.py
│   ├── three.launch.py
│   └── one_node
├── four.launch.py
│   └── two_node
└── five.launch.py

where e.g. one.launch.py launches two.launch.py which again runs a node one_node etc.
You can use this to make your problem easily manageable: test if five.launch.py works, then four.launch.py, three.launch.py ... and go "up the tree". Once all "sub-launch-files" work you can launch them all with one.launch.py.
It's e.g. how NAV2 Stack works, see github.com/ros-navigation/navigation2/tree/main/nav2_bringup.

Could you clearify what you mean by


cpp script that allows me to make a move group node and send
geometry_msgs with classes inside the constraints.h.

especially what you mean with

cpp script

Hope it helps to help yourself. :)

I was able to launch my file for a test script and it worked just fine. Now I am trying to load the right controllers and set up my launch file for a code based off of ompl_constrained_path but am not quite sure which .yaml files to use and how to change them for my specific robot.


Thank you for the pointers, I was able to grasp slightly better how the launch file is meant to be used.
I don't think I expressed it quite correctly as I was trying to set up a move group interface in my C++ code.

